# How to manipulate with magnetic tapes in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, data-storage

I need to do a few basic operations with magnetic tapes on our tape server:

- load tapes
- display statistics (equivalent to `mt stat` command in Linux)
- read/write data onto blocks of tapes

I want to do perform these tasks via an API/library in C/C++ but I'm really struggling with finding instructions/tutorial for beginners.

Can you somehow use *sg* driver, functions from *sg3_utils* or some toying with `ioctl()`?

Comment: It is not clear if you want to code something running on the tape server or elsewhere.....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just need to test writing and reading data to and from tapes (changing the date inbetween)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tapes are usually character devices (usually `/dev/st*`, see [st(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/st.4.html) -which lists relevant [ioctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) arguments- etc...). So use the common [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) syscalls (with a buffer of appropriate size, e.g. 128K bytes).

You might consider [libtar](http://feep.net/libtar/) (to support the `tar` format). You definitely should study the source code of e.g. [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) (and  `mt` contained in it).

Perhaps your tape server has its own API, or some web interface (then use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) or some network protocol.

Comment: As to tape properties, rewinding etc., you use [`ioctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html)s listed in the [linux/mtio.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/mtio.h) header file (on the device node). The `mt-gnu` utility is probably also interesting; it's part of the [cpio](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/) package.

Comment: Could you give me just a short example of sample C code (say just load a tape), pleas? It would really help me a lot...

Comment: Study carefully the `st(4)` and `ioctl(2)` man pages. Study also the source code of `mt`